# How can I load this ajax function on page load?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following code

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">



function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","setfmode.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX set your fmode</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
```

And I need the function `loadXMLDoc()` to be loaded once the page loads. Currently, it can only be loaded if I click the button `Change content`

Also, I don't know why, but the fiddle is not working. The code works just fine on my server.

The button is responsible for loading the php page, what I need to achieve is to load the page without the button, automatically.

Comment: This is a duplicate of which question? Tell me, I need to know.

Answer (score 1):

Put this at the end of the script:

```
window.addEventListener('load', loadXMLDoc);
```

Answer (score -3):

you can try this one:

```
<script>
$(document).on("pageload",function(){
  alert("pageloaded");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Like this? `<script>
$(document).on("pageload",function(){
// my code goes here
});
</script>` 

If so, it's not working.